# Easiest way to convert an int (byte) to a single-character String in Java

Tags: java, string, casting, character, byte

I have an int (-> byte) representing a valid `UTF-8` character and I want to print this single character in a `System.out.println`.

I know these two ways to convert an int representing an UTF-8 byte to a single-character String:

```
int myByte = ...; // For example 67

String sMyByte = String.valueOf((char)((byte)myByte & 0xFF)); // 67 will become "C"

String sMyByte = new String(new byte[]{ (byte)myByte }, StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // 67 will become "C"
```

Both seem a bit long / unreadable and I'd like to know if there is an easier way to convert an int representing a UTF-8 byte to a single-character String. If not I'll probably use the first one of the two above.

Comment: The `& 0xFF` in `(byte)myByte & 0xFF` is unnecessary for at least two reasons: 1. You've said that `myByte` contains a valid UTF-8 "character", which by definition means it's not beyond `0xFF`; and 2. `(byte)myByte` already truncates to 8 bits.

Comment: *"I have an int (-> byte) representing a valid UTF-8 character"* UTF-8 doesn't *have* characters, it has code units, some of which are invalid on their own. A *character* in UTF-8 may be anywhere from one to four bytes long. See: http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not call your int `myByte`; it is in fact a Unicode code point.

The easiest way for you is to use `Character.toChars()`:

```
final String s = new String(Character.toChars(theCodePoint));
```

It will handle each and every code point; after that, it depends on whether the font you use has a glyph for this code point!

Also note that UTF-8 is a *character coding*. You have, in fact, no such thing as a UTF-8 character.

For further inquiry you want to have a look at the [`CharsetEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html) and [`CharsetDecoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) classes.

Answer (score 1):

What about this? .. Like TJ Crowder says, you don't have to convert it into a byte

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int mByte = 67;
    String s = String.valueOf((char)mByte);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

O/P : C

Comment: That still prints a char (it calls the char-param overload of println).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Character.toChars()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toChars%28int%29) here

Eg:

```
System.out.println(Character.toChars(67));
```

Out put:

```
C
```

Comment: The OP says it's UTF-8, not UTF-16. `toChars` expects UTF-16. But that said, if it's one of the single-byte UTF-8 chars, I *suspect* widening that to 16 bits gives you the equivalent single-word UTF-16 character, but I don't know that for certain.

Comment: Yup, according to [this list](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm) and [this list](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-16/list.htm), the first 128 (the only single-byte charts in UTF-8) are the same.

Comment: ("chars" not "charts", sorry)

Answer (score 0):

```
int b = 67;
String s = "" + (char)b;
System.out.println(s);
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

First, we have to make an assumption: You're only dealing with values 0 to 127, because those are the only UTF-8 characters that can be represented by a single UTF-8 code unit (byte). More about UTF-8 and UTF-16 [on the Unicode.org site](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html).

Based on that assumption, we rely on the fact that the first 128 UTF-8 code units (0x00 - 0x7F)  correspond exactly to the first 128 UTF-16 code units (0x0000 - 0x007F). So we can treat your input as a UTF-16 code unit, which is important, because that's what Java's `char` represents. [This list](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm) and [this list](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-16/list.htm) on fileformat.info bear out those first 128 being the same.

Based on the above, then, we get:

```
if (myByte < 0 || myByte > 0x7F) {
    throw /*...relevant exception...*/;
}
String s = Character.toString(myByte);
```

That will call the `Character.toString(char)` method, implicitly cast `myByte` to `char`, and return a string containing one character with the value interpreted in UTF-16.